# What is the distance function type for mixed type data types?

Tags: binary, dataset, cluster-analysis, distance, ordinal

Dears,

In clustering, the selection of distance function I think it depends on the type of data. What about if we have a mixed type data types like (**continuous**) and **categorical**(nominal and/or ordinal) scale and **binary nominal variable**?
Is there is any guide line for a specific distance function type in this case?
If not I would like what is the suitable choice for binary nominal variable?

Thank you,
Shosho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book "Finding Groups in Data" by Kaufman and Rousseeuw covers a decent range of algorithms for different types of data, and gives some explanation on what to do about mixed variable types.  They include information on binary variables.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316801